# What would cause .loc[] to return inconsistent shape?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have a dataframe whoes shape is

```
print(trainData.shape)

(4146, 17)
```

What would be the reason for

```
c =  trainData.loc[0,:]
print(c.shape)
```

returning

```
(17,)
```

I need the output to be a dataframe and not series

[[0]] returns (1,17)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select first row as dataframe, you can use

```py
c =  trainData.loc[[0],:]
# or
c =  trainData.loc[0,:].to_frame().T
```

If you want to select first column as dataframe,

```py
c =  trainData.iloc[:,[0]]
# or
c =  trainData.iloc[:,0].to_frame()
```